# Core Data Serious Application Error at controllerDidChangeContent

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Hello I am stacked now with the error below.

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.
>   An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.
>   Invalid update: invalid number of sections.
>   The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (7) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (6), 
>   plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted). with userInfo (null)

My application has multiple sections tableView.
And error only occurs when I try to insert new section record.
If the section already exists, error not occurred.

The related code is following.

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
       newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
     UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;
     DLog(@"newIndexPath %@",newIndexPath);
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    /*NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        DLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];*/
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Also I put sectionNameKeyPath at fetchResultsController. 
year column does not exist in real core data, it is extension column.

```
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"year" cacheName:@"Master"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could resolve the error by the following changes.
Just for someone in the same situation.

I commented out the following line.

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;
    DLog(@"newIndexPath %@",newIndexPath);
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

And I added the following line.

```
 - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
 {
 // In the simplest, most efficient, case, reload the table view.
     NSError *error = nil;
     if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
         DLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
         abort();
     }
     [self.tableView reloadData];
 }
```