# CoreData serious error when using 2 NSFetchedResultsController on the same table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My problem is I get CoreData Serious error but I don't know why. The error is similar to:

[Core Data Serious Application Error at controllerDidChangeContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24601064/core-data-serious-application-error-at-controllerdidchangecontent)

I have a controller displaying a list of Users (stored in User table in CoreData). Very straight forward.

In a second view controller, I retrieve a list of Users from a server and I also retrieve the Users stored in CoreData to see If we already have the same user locally (In which case I change the color background of the Cell) and I also add a header with a title in the first Cell of the first section.

Here is how I initialize my fetchController in the 1st viewController init constructor:

```
let modelMethodNameForSection = "firstCharOfFirstname"
let requestHelper = NSFetchRequest(entityName: modelEntityClass)
requestHelper.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "friend.groupA == YES")
requestHelper.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

let managedObjectCtx = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: requestHelper, managedObjectContext: managedObjectCtx, sectionNameKeyPath: modelMethodNameForSection, cacheName: nil)
```

Here are the delegates:

```
  //MARK: - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
  func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController)
  {
    tableView!.beginUpdates()
  }

  func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController)
  {
    tableView!.endUpdates()
    if let fetchedObjects = controller.fetchedObjects {
      segmentedControlDelegate?.updateSegment(fetchedObjects.count, listType: ProfilePeopleListType.Friends) //listType doesn t matter here
    }
  }

  func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?)
  {
    switch (type) {
    case .Insert:
      if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
        tableView!.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
      }
      break
    case .Delete:
      if let indexPath = indexPath {
        tableView!.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
      }
      break
    case .Update:
      if let indexPath = indexPath {
        if let cell = tableView!.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? UserViewCell { //We need to check that it's a UserViewCell, because it can be another class
          configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
        }
      } 
      break
    case .Move:
      if let indexPath = indexPath {
        tableView!.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
      }

      if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
        tableView!.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
      }
      break
    }
  }

  func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType)
  {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
      tableView!.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Delete:
      tableView!.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    default:
      return
    }
  }
```

Here is the code for the 2nd viewController displaying results merged with the server:

```
let modelMethodNameForSection = "firstCharOfFirstname"
let requestHelper = NSFetchRequest(entityName: modelEntityClass)
requestHelper.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "friend.groupA == YES")
requestHelper.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

let managedObjectCtx = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: requestHelper, managedObjectContext: managedObjectCtx, sectionNameKeyPath: modelMethodNameForSection, cacheName: nil)
```

**My tableview displays a header containing a title in rows[0] of sections[0] (top of the table)**

```
  //MARK: - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
  //When the local database Friends table changes we are notified
  func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController)
  {

  }

  func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController)
  {

  }

  func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?)
  {

    //We refresh the lists with new data from local Database
    let listFriendsFilterBlock = peopleListWithOwnerFriendsFilter()
    tableView?.reloadData()
  }

  func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType)
  {
    //We don't have any sections in the users list merged with server data

  }
```

**EDIT**
Crash log:

> [;2016-03-16 18:51:10.511 *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView
>   _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3512.29.5/UITableView.m:1720
>   2016-03-16 18:51:10.511 CoreData: error: Serious application error. 
>   An exception was caught from the delegate of
>   NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section
>   after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in
>   that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows
>   inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus
>   or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved
>   in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

Comment: tell us the serious error message you get

Comment: here it is, problem with rows numbers.

Comment: I really don't understand how the exception can occur knowing that NSFetchedResultsController is not even aware of the tableView (We don't even give a pointer to it in the code)

Answer (score 0):

From the error message your FRC is telling you (the delegate) that something has changed, as a result of this you're updating your data source data, but you aren't properly telling the table view about the insertions / deletions.

In this specific case 1 item has been inserted and the table view has not been told about any insertions.

This is possibly, though it's hard to tell, related to:

```
//We refresh the lists with new data from local Database
let listFriendsFilterBlock = peopleListWithOwnerFriendsFilter()
tableView?.reloadData()
```

because that kind of approach to refreshing the table should be implemented in `controllerDidChangeContent` not `didChangeObject`. You should know that the change is complete before reloading.

Comment: I moved my code in controllerDidChangeContent but I still have the problem. One problem is I don't really have a way to know which tableview triggers the issue. All I know is that the tableView layout with the switch-case gets broken when the error happens. Like the tableview top content inset become a really huge white space . The second problem is that I would like to NOT have to tell about insertion/deletion on this second view controller as I display data mixed between server and client... I prefer to simply refresh the whole list for now. Why a link between coredata a nd tableview though

Comment: Is the second table update really driven by the FRC then? I'm not sure why you don't know which to update as they're in different controllers.

Comment: The second tableView is just using a datasource that is a merge between FRC fetchedObjects and server data. When coredata has a change, I request the server and reload the table entirely. Maybe I have to empty it before hands too ?